# how to external function which get fire on every request in mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on **already develop project** in which now i need to check for the **subscription** is **expired** or not on every http **request**. So I need have write a **dll** which contain the expiry date and validation function to validate the subscription to if subscription is expired the system redirect to subscription renewal page to renew subscription. if user renew subscription then user get the new ddl with updated dates now user just upload this file in bin folder.
I am very new for such kind of functionality please give the way to have this done. i have google it I have got [ActionFilterAttribute](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs) but for this i need to add the filter on **every action(I dont want to do this)** if any one remove this then i will by pass the validation.

Comment: You can apply an ActionFilter to a controller (so it applies to all methods in the controller), or register it globally (applies to every method in every controller)

Comment: There are thousands of examples on the web showing how to create custom `ActionFilters` including custom `AuthorizationAttribute`'s

Comment: No. Read my first comment. Your can register it in `global.asax` so it applies to every action in every controller

Answer (score 1):

You can create BaseController like

```html
[YourNewAttribute]
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
```

and then inherit all your controllers from it